# Javascript : ParseInt the computed transform matrix values returns NaN

Tags: javascript, parsing, transform

So I have this `transform` computed style

```
matrix3d(1.5, -7, 2, 0, 7, 1.5, 0, 0, -3, 1, 1, 0, 100, 0, 0, 1)
```

Next I want to transform to an array of numbers

```
var s = window.getComputedStyle(element);
var mattrixArray = s.replace(/3d|matrix|(|)|\s|/g,'').split(','), l = mattrixArray.length;
for (var i=0; i<l; i++){
  mattrixArray[i] = parseInt(mattrixArray[i],10);
}
console.log(mattrixArray)
```

This returns

```
[NaN, -7, 2, 0, 7, 1.5, 0, 0, -3, 1, 1, 0, 100, 0, 0, 1]
```

If I don't do `parseInt(value)` it shows correct but it's a `string`, what to do?

Comment: What is `s`. Please add the description

Comment: Your Regex is incorrect and does not renove the `(` and `)`, resulting in the wrong values for the first element

Comment: If you had looked at the value of `mattrixArray` you would have seen the problem almost immediately, since the first element will begin with `(`. Escape the parentheses in your regex.

Comment: Like this? `s.replace(/3d|matrix|\(|\)|\s|/g,'')`

Comment: Thank you @JamesAllardice up-voted and I wish you an excellent day, you made my day :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not escape the `(` and `)` in your regex.

```
/3d|matrix|(|)|\s|/g
           ^ ^
```

If you correct this to look like this:

```
/3d|matrix|\(|\)|\s|/g
```

the regex properly removes the parantheses as well, resulting in an array that you can succesfully stick into `parseInt` or `parseFloat`:

```
["1.5", "-7", "2", "0", "7", "1.5", "0", "0", "-3", "1", "1", "0", "100", "0", "0", "1"]
```

Comment: Disclaimer: I was writing my answer already when James Allardice and thednp posted their corrections

Answer (score 0):

Your regexp doesn't replace the parenthesis at all. Needs some escaping!

```
var s = window.getComputedStyle(element);
var mattrixArray = s.replace(/3d|matrix|\(|\)|\s|/g,'').split(',')
  , l = mattrixArray.length;
for (var i=0; i<l; i++){
    mattrixArray[i] = parseFloat(mattrixArray[i],10);
}
console.log(mattrixArray);
```

Also use `parseFloat` instead of `parseInt` so you will get the real values instead of rounded values.

Alternatively you could do:

```
var mattrixArray = s.split("(")[1].split(")")[0].split(',')
```

Edit: Just tested, splitting 3 times is about 4 times faster than using an regexp.

Comment: 3 split means 3 loops what about : s.split(/\(|,|\)/).slice(1,-1).map( function(v){ return parseFloat(v); });